# Copy the profile from one license type to another

Tags: profile, licenses, partner-communities

We have our partner community up and running.
We were using the Partner Community license type, with 3 different profiles. (sharing sets and page layouts assigned).

We are now moving to the 'Partner Community Login' license type,. I noticed, that I can not use the same profile, and I need to create new profiles to match the license type.

How can I copy the profile from one license type to another ? I have multiple settings defined in the profile, and I don't want to loose them.

Comment: Best to switch to perm sets. If you have `sf` or `sfdx` CLI you can pull the profiles and their permissions and repackage these into perm sets.

Comment: I would still need the profile for other settings, will I use an stub/empty profile than? Can you elaborate please on the pull process with SF ?

Comment: Every user must have a profile that is linked to their license. Yes, a basically empty profile is ideal, along with the necessary perm set(s) to control permissions. To find out about the CLI take the [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/sfdx_app_dev). It may seem like a lot to understand at first but will really help you be more effective.